# how to edit a record?

Tags: apex, visualforce, datatable, table

I have created a table with edit option.Whenever clicking the particular row edit link the whole table rows enabled to edited. but i want to edit a particular row.

> apex

```
public class account2task1
{


public string id;
public Boolean bool {get;set;}
public Boolean bool1 {get;set;}
public List<account> contt{get;set;}
public Integer counterNumber{ get; set; }
    public account2task1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    bool = true;
     id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

     contt=[select id,name,accountnumber,phone from account limit 5];
    }

public void save2() {

    bool =false;

}

}
```

> VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="account" extensions="account2task1" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form > 


        <apex:pageBlock >

     <apex:pageBlockSection >
     <apex:dataTable value="{!contt}"   var="a" cellpadding="4" border="1" width="100">
                 <apex:column headervalue="Action">
                 <apex:commandLink value="Edit"  action="{!save2}"  >

                    </apex:commandLink>

                 </apex:column>  
           <apex:column headervalue="Account name" width="50"  >
           <apex:inputField value="{!a.name}" html-disabled="{!bool}" id="a1" />
           <script>document.getElementById('{!$Component.a1}').disabled = {!bool}; </script> </apex:column> 

                 <apex:column headervalue="Account number" width="50" >
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.accountnumber}" html-disabled="{!bool}" id="a2" />
                <script>document.getElementById('{!$Component.a2}').disabled = {!bool}; </script> </apex:column> 


</apex:dataTable>


</apex:pageBlockSection>

      </apex:pageBlock> 

   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Is this you? Did you create a new username to post another question? Why not just stay under the same name? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87664/how-to-edit-a-particular-record

Comment: mahi did'not understand your code please revise this code and put revised code of class

Comment: The best way to do it, IMO is to put a wrapper class around your data so you can bind buttons directly to those rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly easy to do with standard Visualforce. 
See the example below. You may have to adapt it as per your use case and refine it a bit.

**Controller**

```
public class AccountController {

    public List<Account> accountList{get; set;}
    public Id editId {get; set;}

    public AccountController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        accountList = [select id,name,billingcity,Phone,Website from Account limit 20];
    }

    public void saveRecord(){
        update accountList;
        editId = null;
    }
}
```

**Visualforce**

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountController">    
<apex:pageBlock id="pbId">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountList}" var="acc">          
        <apex:column>
            <apex:commandButton value="Edit" reRender="pbId" rendered="{!acc.id!=editId}">
                <apex:param assignTo="{!editId}" name="edit" value="{!acc.id}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>

            <apex:commandButton value="Save" reRender="pbId" rendered="{!acc.id==editId}" action="{!saveRecord}">
            </apex:commandButton>
        </apex:column>        
        <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!acc.name}" rendered="{!acc.id!=editId}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.name}" rendered="{!acc.id==editId}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">City</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!acc.BillingCity}" rendered="{!acc.id!=editId}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.BillingCity}" rendered="{!acc.id==editId}"/>                
        </apex:column>

    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

So what I am doing is I remember what row I clicked edit on by saving it in a variable, and I rerender the table. When the table variable iterates, I check whether this one was selected for editing, and if it is then I render the `inputfield`, or else the `outputfield`.